# Formatting a file with two different types of code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible in Visual Studio Code to format the file as PowerShell but only a part of the file as SQL?

I have a PowerShell file that pulls data out of a SQL Server database and manipulates it then emails the results.  When looking at the file the SQL string looks like a plain string and I was wondering that while the file was a PowerShell file I could get the SQL code formatted as SQL code?